# Custos relacionados aos códigos do AWS Lambda e o S3

Tags: amazon-aws

Quando uma função AWS Lambda possui códigos que estão salvos em um bucket no S3, o acesso aos fontes para cada função iniciada, respeita a política de custos do S3?

Um exemplo seria, a cada função que inicia a mesma baixa o código do S3 e eu pago a taxa de transferência e taxa de acesso como se fosse eu mesmo acessando e baixando o arquivo?

Obrigado.

Comment: Sim, é um request como outro qualquer. Da uma olhada nessa documentação, em baixo tem um exemplo citando o S3:
https://aws.amazon.com/pt/lambda/pricing/

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta é um pouco confusa e a parte do "a cada função que inicia a mesma baixa o código do S3" gera interpretações diferentes, mas vamos aos pontos:

**Function Code**

Se você está se referindo ao Function Code vs Invoke(start da execução do container) não acredito que ele "baixe" o seu código a cada execução.

Primeiro, o container pode ser reutilizado por um período indeterminado de tempo, então se o container está "quente" a execução pode(ou não) considerar o código que já rodou anteriormente.

Segundo, o "cold start" do container já leva um tempinho considerável, agora, imagine se o package(zip, jar e etc) tem 50MB e o container precise baixar o código a cada execução, a latência disso seria um pouco bizarra e seu custo no S3 também iria subir.

Apesar de eu não encontrar a documentação oficial de como essa parte do core funciona não faz muito sentido acreditar que seu código é baixado a cada execução.

Obs.: Faça um teste, faça o deploy da versão 1 do Lambda Function e depois vá no S3(atualize apenas no S3) e atualize o package pra versão 2(algum print diferente e etc). Veja se durante todas as execuções a versão 2 foi utilizada.

**Consumo de Recursos no S3**

Se você está se referindo ao acesso que seu código faz em recursos no S3(exemplo: seu código faz o upload ou download de imagens) daí sim a política de custos do S3 é aplicada normalmente.

Caso você descubra algo diferente poste aqui, sempre achei um pouco obscura a documentação da AWS.

Comment: Tom, desculpe a pergunta meio confusa, mas me refiro ao Function Code. Quando eu crio uma aplicação pelo Serverless Framework, o mesmo salva o código em um bucket e linka o mesmo a função lambda para que possa ser baixado. A princípio ele realmente não fica baixando sempre que inicia uma execução pois pode estar quente, mas quando se faz necessário, será que a Amazon está cobrando o  acesso ao S3 e o Get do arquivo (.zip)?

Comment: Então, também entendi isso da sua pergunta. Acredito que o core da aws faça o GET do arquivo apenas uma vez a cada versão nova que você faz o deploy. Pra validar isso basta fazer o deploy do Lambda Function e na sequência remover o arquivo zip que o framework upou no S3, acredito que tudo vai continuar funcionando normalmente sem precisar baixar seu código a cada vez que o container "esfrie".

Comment: Show, realmente é interessante se ele baixar o código somente uma vez por atualização da stack. Vou dar uma testada, obrigado.